# eqution of the plane knowing two conditions

Tags: geometry

How can I find the equation of the plane $\pi$ such that:

$$\pi || \pi_{1}: x_{1}+3x_{2}-2x_{3}+15=0$$ and $$d_{1}: \frac{x_{1}+3}{4}=\frac{x_{2}-2}{2}=\frac{x_{3}-1}{5} \subset \pi.$$
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the normal vector for $\pi_1$ is  $(1,3,-2)$, the equation of any plane parallel to $\pi_1$ has normal vector  $(1,3,-2)$.

So, the equation of the plane parallel to $\pi_1$ and containing the point $(a,b,c)$ is $$1(x_1-a)+3(x_2-b)-2(x_3-c)=0.$$

Take any point $(a,b,c)$ on the line $d_1$ and substitute into the above. The resulting plane will contain $d_1$, since, as easily verified, $d_1$ does not intersect $\pi_1$.